# Tesseract OCR iOS detect text from handwritten form and autofill online form with the text

Tags: ios, objective-c, ocr, tesseract, handwriting-recognition

I have used Tesseract for extracting text from scanned documents and I am able to fetch text from scanned documents. Now I want to extract text from a handwritten form (Hard copy) and use that text to autofill my online form (soft copy of the same handwritten form).
Anybody knows how to do that?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract OCR is quite powerful, but does have the following limitations:

- Unlike some OCR engines (like those used by the U.S. Postal Service to sort mail), **Tesseract is unable to recognize handwriting and is limited to about 64 fonts in total**.
- Tesseract requires a bit of preprocessing to improve the OCR results; images need to be scaled appropriately, have as much image contrast as possible, and have horizontally-aligned text.
- Finally, Tesseract OCR only works on Linux, Windows, and Mac OS X.

Original article : 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/93276/implementing-tesseract-ocr-ios

Comment: Do You know any other option than tesseract please provide a link?

Comment: https://www.podfeet.com/blog/2016/02/myscript-stylus/ I think this SDK may be interesting. Please mark the question as answered if you think my answer is helpful.